# Python - How to show addition of integers digits

Tags: python, integer, addition, digit

I want to show in a line the addition of the digits of a positive integer.
For example if input is

```
4316
```

I want it to output

```
4+3+1+6
```

Also the input can be any x amount of digits.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: we aren't here to do your homework for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `str`on the number and `str.join` the result of that:

```
i = 4316

print("+".join(str(i)))
4+3+1+6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number=5132
print "+".join([c for c in str(number)])
5+1+3+2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more elegant solution encapsulated in a function which is more powerful, because any string or any dataformat which is convertable into a string can be used.

```
def add_operator(operator, number):
    return str(operator).join(str(number))

add_operator("+", 4316)  # or print(add_operator("+", 4316))
'4+3+1+6'
```

See also the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method. You only have to give something iterable as a parameter for `str.join`. A `str` is iterable, that's why you have to convert the number (`int`) to a string (`str`).

This solution scales up, see these examples:

```
add_operator("-", 4316)
'4-3-1-6'
add_operator("*", 123456)
'1*2*3*4*5*6'
add_operator("xyz", "000")
'0xyz0xyz0'
```